Asian Floating Strike option and its gamma
Running MC simulations for Asian Floating Strike options - where the strike is the arithmetic average of the stock over the life of the option so the payoff is S-avg(S).
I approximate greeks, and I always get a gamma equal to zero. I suspect this is due to the averaging strike, anyone could help with the intuition behind this? Thanks!!
